# Angular JS and Kendo dynamic Url for DataSource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a autocomplete textbox and when a user types into to it i would like to pass the value to the url that the json calls as this would return the data i require in the search

this is the html i am currently using

```
<inputtype="text"kendo-autocompletek-data-source="customersDataSource"k-data-text-field="'RegisteredName'"k-data-value-field="'SupplierId'"ng-model="SearchData.TradingName"k-min-length="3" />
```

This is the JS i currently have

```
$scope.customersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            read: {

                url: "/Supplier/GetSuppliersAutoCompelte",
                dataType: "json"
            }

        },
        schema: {
            type: "json",
            data: "SupplierNames",
            model: {
                fields: {
                    fields: {
                        Field1: { field: "Field1", type: "number" },
                        Field2: { field: "Field2", type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

now in the url if the user types abc for example in the searchdata.tradingname then i would like the url in my js to be shown as

```
/Supplier/GetSuppliersAutoCompelte?tradingname=abc
```

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/OzUJE

Comment: Thanks for the dojo example @calinaadi, the issue i am having is i need to  pass the value typed into the textbox to the service being called in the url so the url needs to be updated to contain the value passed from the textbox

Comment: Wacht the requests passed to server see that is happening.